# How do I check if all of the tags associated to the playlist_slides exists in the tags associated in screens table

Tags: sql, mysql

For context here is a simplified way of my DB Structure

[image]

Table definitions and data sample :

```
CREATE TABLE `screens` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `playlist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;


CREATE TABLE `playlist_slides` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `resource_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `screens` VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `playlist` VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `playlist_slides` VALUES (3, 2);

INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (3, 3, 1);

INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (4, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (5, 3, 3);

INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (3);
```

I would like to check if all of the tags assigned to the playlist_slides table exists in the tags assigned in screens table.

Currently I tried doing it like this:

```sql
SELECT
  `media_content_array`.*,
  `current_screen_tags`.`screen_tags`
FROM `screens`
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    `playlist_slides`.`playlist_id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      playlist_content_tags.tag_id
      ORDER BY playlist_content_tags.tag_id
    ) AS tag_ids
  FROM `playlist_slides`
  LEFT JOIN `playlist_content_tags`
  ON `playlist_slides`.`id` = `playlist_content_tags`.`item_id`
  GROUP BY `playlist_slides`.`playlist_id`
) AS `media_content_array`
ON `media_content_array`.`playlist_id` = `screens`.`playlist_id`
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT
    `screens`.`id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      resource_tags.tag_id
      ORDER BY resource_tags.tag_id
    ) AS screen_tags 
  FROM `screens`
  LEFT JOIN `resource_tags`
  ON `screens`.`id` = `resource_tags`.`item_id`
  WHERE `screens`.`id` = ?
  GROUP BY `screens`.`id`
) AS `current_screen_tags`
ON `screens`.`id` = `current_screen_tags`.`id`
WHERE `screens`.`id` = ?
AND `media_content_array`.`tag_ids` LIKE CONCAT('%', `current_screen_tags`.`screen_tags`, '%');
```

as you can see i used

```
media_content_array.tag_ids LIKE CONCAT('%', media_content_array.tag_ids, '%')
```

it worked only if tag_ids is on the right sequence.
Not sure how ill do it any other way.

Comment: Can you please share your tables definitions instead of the picture ?

Comment: i've added more details @AmiraBedhiafi

Comment: your table definitions contains some errors I will update the question I just need your expected output

Comment: INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (1, 1, 3); this is violationg the primary key constraint 
since you inserted before INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (1, 1, 1);

Comment: i fixed the errors

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: The table `playlist` seems to have no useful columns; why does the table exist??  If you have left out other columns (that have useful info), please at least add a line "..." to indicate such.

Comment: The table name `playlist_slides` sounds like a many-to-many relationship between playlist(s) and slide(s).  If so, where is `slide_id`??

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `screens` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `playlist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;


CREATE TABLE `playlist_slides` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `resource_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `screens` VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `playlist` VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `playlist_slides` VALUES (3, 2);

INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (3, 3, 1);

/*INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO `resource_tags` VALUES (3, 3, 3); */

INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES (3);
```

```
SELECT 
    ps.`id` AS playlist_slide_id,
    ps.`playlist_id` AS playlist_slide_playlist_id,
    ps_tags.tag_ids AS playlist_slide_tags,
    s.`id` AS screen_id,
    s_tags.tag_ids AS screen_tags,
    IF(
        ps_tags.tag_ids IS NULL,
        'No tags associated with playlist_slides',
        IF(
            s_tags.tag_ids IS NULL,
            'No tags associated with screens',
            IF(
                FIND_IN_SET(ps_tags.tag_ids, s_tags.tag_ids),
                'All tags of playlist_slides are in screens',
                'Not all tags of playlist_slides are in screens'
            )
        )
    ) AS result
FROM `playlist_slides` ps
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `playlist_slides`.`id` AS slide_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            `resource_tags`.`tag_id` 
            ORDER BY `resource_tags`.`tag_id`
        ) AS tag_ids
    FROM `playlist_slides`
    LEFT JOIN `resource_tags`
    ON `playlist_slides`.`id` = `resource_tags`.`item_id`
    GROUP BY `playlist_slides`.`id`
) AS `ps_tags`
ON ps.`id` = ps_tags.slide_id

LEFT JOIN `screens` s
ON ps.`playlist_id` = s.`playlist_id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        `screens`.`id`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            `resource_tags`.`tag_id` 
            ORDER BY `resource_tags`.`tag_id`
        ) AS tag_ids
    FROM `screens`
    LEFT JOIN `resource_tags`
    ON `screens`.`id` = `resource_tags`.`item_id`
    GROUP BY `screens`.`id`
) AS `s_tags`
ON s.`id` = `s_tags`.`id`;
```

| playlist_slide_id | playlist_slide_playlist_id | playlist_slide_tags | screen_id | screen_tags | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | *null* | 1 | 1,2,3 | No tags associated with playlist_slides |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0hhndvp_)

Comment: Hey Amira, Thanks for this! I tried your fiddle but it seems to not work as well even if the playlist_slide_tags is equal to screen_tags

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, finding tags assigned on playlist and not assigned to screens, below query will work.

1. Group all tag_ids and get their count for each side.
2. Tags on both screen and playslist_slide  having different count means some were not assigned, we extract the difference as number of tags not assigned.
3. Tags not in screens are treated as not assigned by default.

   ```
     WITH playlist_slides_tags AS (
     SELECT tag_id,count(*) AS tag_count  FROM resource_tags r
     INNER JOIN playlist_slides p ON r.item_id = p.id
     GROUP BY tag_id
        ),
     screen_tags AS (
        SELECT tag_id,count(*) AS tag_count  FROM resource_tags r
        INNER JOIN screens s ON r.item_id = s.id
        GROUP BY tag_id
     ),
     unassigned_tags AS (
        SELECT tag_id,p.tag_count - s.tag_count AS tag_count FROM playlist_slides_tags p
        INNER JOIN  screen_tags s USING(tag_id)  WHERE  p.tag_count != s.tag_count
        UNION 
        SELECT tag_id, p.tag_count FROM playlist_slides_tags p
        LEFT JOIN screen_tags s USING(tag_id)  WHERE s.tag_id IS NULL
     )
     SELECT tag_id, tag_count FROM unassigned_tags
   ```

Answer (score -1):

"I would like to check if all of the tags assigned to the playlist_slides table exists in the tags assigned in screens table."
Other answers, whilst correct, have built on your existing query... which is exceedingly complex. You can break down this problem into 2 parts:

1. Find the tag id of of each playlist_slide (using a join)
2. Checking which tags do not exist in resource_tags (using not in)

   ```
   select
       *
   from
       playlist_slides ps join resource_tags rt on ps.id = rt.item_id
   WHERE   
       rt.tag_id not in (select id from tags)
   ```

Technically though, you don't even need to do a join, you can just select the tag_id from resource_tag and use the same condition